# All arrays must be of the same length - creating pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is the full code of the program it still gives the same error , how can l solve it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#Connecting to the url
quotes_url = "https://quotes.toscrape.com/"
response = requests.get(quotes_url)

Quotes=[]
Quotes_by=[]
Tags = []

#checking status of url
if response.status_code ==200:
    url_contents = response.text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(url_contents,'html.parser')
    
    quote_rows = doc.find_all('div',{'class':'quote'})

    for quote in quote_rows:
        quotes_tag = doc.find_all('span',{'class','text'})
        quotes_by_tag = doc.find_all('small',{'class':'author'})
        Tags_tag = doc.find_all('div',{'class':'tags'})
        
        '''Error :
        All arrays must be of the same length
        Code
        for tag_tags in Tags_tag:
            tag_tags = doc.find_all('a',{'class':'tag'})
            for tag in tag_tags:
                Tags.append(tag.text.strip())
        '''
        Tags.append({
        'qoute':q.get_text() if (q:= quote.select_one('.text')) else None,
        'tags':[tag.get_text() for tag in quote.select('a.tag')]
    })
        for quote in quotes_tag:
             Quotes.append(quote.text.strip())
        #Appending to the list
        for quote_by in quotes_by_tag:
            Quotes_by.append(quote_by.text.strip())
        
    quotes_dict = {
        'Author':Quotes_by,
        'Tags':Tags,
        'Quote':Quotes
        }
    
    Quotes_df = pd.DataFrame(quotes_dict)
    print(Quotes_df)
    Quotes_df.to_csv('quote.csv',index=None)
else:
    print("Error: %s" % response.status_code)
```

So l dont know whats wrong when l try to print the data frame, through my research of study am finding different approaching on writing the codes when l try those they work

Answer (score 1):

You got a flattened list of tags because you picked them all at once.

To make a nested list (*for each quote separately*), you can try something like below :

```
Tags = [
    [tag.get_text() for tag in quote.select(".tag")]
    for quote in doc.select(".quote")
]
```

Output :

```
[['change', 'deep-thoughts', 'thinking', 'world'],
 ['abilities', 'choices'],
 ['inspirational', 'life', 'live', 'miracle', 'miracles'],
 ['aliteracy', 'books', 'classic', 'humor'],
 ['be-yourself', 'inspirational'],
 ['adulthood', 'success', 'value'],
 ['life', 'love'],
 ['edison', 'failure', 'inspirational', 'paraphrased'],
 ['misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt'],
 ['humor', 'obvious', 'simile']]
```

Used input :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://quotes.toscrape.com"
doc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: for showing up the nesting approach +1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Timeless's comments on generating the nested `list`.

Always treat a collection of lists with caution, as you can rarely guarantee that their lengths are always the same for the generation of a dataframe. You will therefore run into exactly the same problem at the latest in the case of missing elements (tags check https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/).

Use dicts instead - also if a key or value is missing, it will simply be filled with `Nan` by creating your dataframe. But it can't hurt to always perform a check anyway:

```
for quote in soup.select('.quote'):
    data.append({
        'qoute':q.get_text() if (q:= quote.select_one('.text')) else None,
        'tags':[tag.get_text() for tag in quote.select('a.tag')]
    })
```

###### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

data = []

for quote in soup.select('.quote'):
    data.append({
        'qoute':q.get_text() if (q:= quote.select_one('.text')) else None,
        'tags':[tag.get_text() for tag in quote.select('a.tag')]
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```